# What is a Remitting Entity?

Tags: mutual-funds, terminology

In mutual fund jargon, what is meant by a remitting entity?

Comment: In what context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remitting* means paying, and *entity* means organization, such as a company, partnership, government department, etc.  *Remitting entity* is legalistic jargon used to refer to an organization that is sending money somewhere.  Why it is sending money and to whom is not implicit in the term, but depends on the larger context of the usage of the term.

Comment: So if I have an online brokerage account with BMO and it is sending money to TSX to buy me stocks, then BMO is a remitting entity?

Comment: *Entity* also includes individuals. So if you send money to BMO, you are also a *remitting entity*. This is why I asked "in what context?", since all "remitting entity" means is a person or organization sending money somewhere.